# unable to print the value of field in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table using query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bus` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hindi` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and dumped the values as :

```
INSERT INTO `bus` (`id`, `name`, `hindi`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1'),
(2, '1A', '1ए'),
(3, 'AC1', 'एसी 1');
```

When I am trying to fetch result from this table as follow :

```
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($startb))
{ 
    $bus3 = $row3['busid'];
    $startb2 = mysql_query("select `name` from `bus` where `id`='$bus3'");
    $startb3 = mysql_fetch_array($startb2);
    print_r($startb3);
    $startbu = $startb3['name'];
}
```

When I am trying to print the value of `$startb3` then it is giving the value as follow :

```
   Array ( [0] => AC1 [name] => AC1 )
```

It is not printing the value of fields `id` and `hindi`. Please tell me guys What I am missing in the query ?

Comment: try using `mysqli_fetch_array` instead. the former is no more supported by new versions of `php`

Comment: What is the value of $startb?  also you are referencing a key that does not exist in your table `busid`

Comment: for startb I am using query $startb = mysql_query("select case when a.position < b.position then a.busid when a.position > b.position then a.busid else null end as busid from (select busid,position from route where routid=$start) a join (select busid,position from route where routid=$result2) b on a.busid = b.busid") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Besides these, u have a `mysql_query` in ur while loop, which costs too much. u have major problems in urcode. try googling for a beginning tut

Comment: `mysql_query("select name from bus where id='$bus3'");`      you are fetching only name, try to get all values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not selecting the id and hindi feilds in you query. Try like this:

```
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($startb))
{ 
    $bus3 = $row3['busid'];
    $startb2 = mysql_query("select `name`, `id`, `hindi` from `bus` where `id`='$bus3'");
    $startb3 = mysql_fetch_array($startb2);
    print_r($startb3);
    $startbu = $startb3['name'];
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Oh I got it sorry for the inc0nviences it saved me

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement is:

```
$startb2 = mysql_query("select `name` from `bus` where `id`='$bus3'")
```

if you want the other values it should be:

```
$startb2 = mysql_query("select `name`, `id`, `hindi` from `bus` where `id`='$bus3'")
```

or

```
$startb2 = mysql_query("select * from `bus` where `id`='$bus3'")
```

Also as mentioned in a previous comment, `msql_` is deprecated please use `msqli_` with variable binding, or PDO in the future.